# Add the Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C to Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, google-plus

I'm trying to make an iPhone application that use Google+ API. I found http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client

Now, I'm trying to add this API im my Xcode project by drag and drop the source folder in API. I also linked static library in build phase of target. But after build of the project, lots of errors are there.

Further, I found document for adding API to project from here http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary. I followed the same steps but still getting error.

Comment: Which version of XCode are you using?

Comment: Hi chirag, i am using xcode version 4.0.2. errors are related with Xcode Version??

Comment: Can you update the question with the precise errors you're seeing in your logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your last question, the sample Google+ Objective-C application is located here:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FExamples%2FPlusSample

Comment: I dont know where i was making mistake to add GTL.xcodeproject in my Xcode project.I had set **'header path'** as well as **'other Linker'**  too..but faild..so i just drage the class files from GTL.xcodeproject an compile them in my Project and its works.. :) thanx for help Chirag...May be i was making mistake to give dependency to my project.